# Does Titanium Studio have an "Immediate Window"?

Tags: titanium

I'm new to Titanium Studio and am wondering, does it had an equivalent to Visual Studio's "Immediate Window," so that I can do runtime execution of random statements and the like?  Thanks!

Nathan

Comment: plz, specify what you want to do actually....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is a tool called TiShadow that I think might help you